# How to get specific data points in python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently was able to get data to capture size at 24022 (which is x1), but I want to separate the data further into 'bid' or 'ask.' So I want to get the data for when its size is 24022, and ask. Another one for when size is 24022 and bid. T

```
headers = ['ticker', 'size', 'price', 'unix','type','date']
dtypes = {'ticker': 'str', 'size': 'float', 'price': 'float', 'unix': 'float','type': 'str','date': 'str'}
parse_dates = ['date']
btcnow = pd.read_csv('new 113-115.csv', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)
#btc105=pd.read_excel('11-3-11-5 data.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1",header=None)
#btc103=btc103.append(btc105,ignore_index = True)
now3 = pd.DataFrame(btcnow, columns=['size','date','type','price'])
now4 = pd.DataFrame(btcnow, columns=['date','price','size'])
x1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "date"]
y1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "size"]
```

I tried the following code, but it's saying can't compare the two data types:

```
y1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 11111 & now3["type"] == 'ASK','size']
```

The data looks like the following:
[data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z3SO.jpg)

Comment: `y1 = now3.loc[(now3["size"] == 11111) & (now3["type"] == 'ASK'),'size']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your dataframe, for example I have created a sample .csv that has similar data to what you have so with columns type and size we are looking for.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(r"<PATH>") # Load full dataset
```

Then we can filter it by type and size as such:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['type'] == "BID") & (df['size'] == 24022)]
```

Comment: I get it to work, but how can I set it up so I can graph those points?

Comment: Because the code I had above:x1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "date"];
y1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "size"], allowed me to graph the size 24022 on the graph.